# Making one exclude cookie for multiple google analytics sites

Tags: google-analytics, tracking, cookie, web-traffic

I've got multiple sites all with different google analytics profiles in them (managed under one account).

I would like to exclude everyones traffic in the office from all the sites. To do this when we clear the cookies / get a new device we have to go to the page on each site that has the exclude cookie this is fine but when you have to do it 6 times for each machine its a bit tedious. Is there a way to have one cookie for all sites?

Because both the cookie and the tracking code need to be on the same page would it be possible to have one page with all the tracking codes on it and all the cookies so that it would simultaneously exclude our traffic from all sites?

Answer (score 1):

An easier way of doing this is to define a filter based on your office IP address and exclude all traffic from that IP address when viewing the stats for your sites. [This article](http://support.google.com/analytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1034823) describes how to create a filter. You want to create a filter that says
`Exclude` `traffic from the IP addresses` `that are equal to` and then put in your office IP address.

Comment: That is the prefered method for excluding traffic, but i beleve i have a dynamic ip so it wouldnt work

Comment: You could simply opt out of ga tracking for each device, this would then cover all ga tracking on all sites
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/user-opt-out